# Problems connecting to SVN server

Tags: svn

I have on the server (Windows Server 2008 first edition) installed SVN (Subversion Edge).Perform basic setup SVN.Created repository and carried out more than six months working with SVN. However, during the last month are constant problems with connection to the SVN and the following error:

> Unable to connect to a repository at url  http://.../svn/RCNMAIN
>     The requested name is correct, but the data of the requested type was found.

After a while the connection is proceeding normally. Sometimes it happens that the tree itself is displayed normally, and its subtree is not (there is a similar error, I have not filled it, so I can not say for sure).

**Question:** How do I fix this situation? Maybe you need to change any server settings SVN?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem in the DNS, i.e. If instead of a string URL:

> http://netserver3.rcn.local:18080/svn/RCNMAIN

to make a line like this URL:

> http://10.0.1.10:18080/svn/RCNMAIN

everything is connected.